# Starting value in optimization algorithms

Tags: c#, accord.net

I am trying to use the L-BFGS solver in Accord.net maths package in C#.
However, I cannot find how to define the starting value of the optimization.
How can we define it ?

According to official examples, the following syntax defines the initial value of x in the optimization process. However it does not work properly in the following example - as if another starting point was used by the algorithm.

```
//Target function to minimize;
public double f(double[] x) { 
   double z = Math.Cos(x[0])-0.2*x[0] + x[1] * x[1]; //Function with multiple local minima : x ~ { (2n+1)pi , 0 }
   return z;
  }

//Gradient
  public double[] g(double[] x) { 
      double[] grad = {-Math.Sin(x[0])-0.2 , 2 * x[1]};
      return grad;
  }

  double[] x = {3*3.141592,0}; // Starting value (local minimum, -2.88)

  var lbfgs = new BroydenFletcherGoldfarbShanno(numberOfVariables: 2, function: f, gradient: g);

  bool success = lbfgs.Minimize();
  double minValue = lbfgs.Value;
  double[] solution = lbfgs.Solution; // {3.34,0} This solution is a local min that has a higher value (-1.65) than the local min next to which we started !!
```

Comment: Have you tried `lbfgs.Minimize(x);`?

Comment: That works !! Thank you, you made me save a lot of time :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is simply:
lbfgs.Minimize(x);
Thank you "500 - Internal Server Error" !